# С#: отображение сообщения в зависимости от значения свойства gridView

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

Имеется форма (winforms) в которой есть gridView1.
У gridView1 есть свойство отвечающее за доступность редактирования значений в таблице OptionsBehavior.ReadOnly (значения true и false). Пользователь может переключать эти значения.
Также допустим у нас есть некий Label1 (или любой другой эдитор) куда может выводиться сообщение о том, доступно ли редактирование или нет.
Вопрос:
Как реализовать проверку значения OptionsBehavior.ReadOnly в реальном времени, для вывода в Label1 соответствующего сообщения?

Comment: `GridView` или `DataGridView`?

Comment: именно gridView. Но я думаю не так важно какой именно объект. Главное это то, что у объекта (в моём случае gridView) нет готовых событий на которые можно подписаться. поэтому и интересует как реализовать проверку значения любого свойства

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идет о DataGridView, то есть уже готовое событие, на которое нужно подписаться -
DataGridView.ReadOnlyChanged Event, а после его срабатывания меняй свой Label1.

```
private void DataGridView1_ReadOnlyChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

   label1.Text = "ReadOnly";
}
```

Comment: К сожалению у меня не  DataGridView, а именно gridView (из набора Devexpress). Но я думаю не так важно какой именно объект. Главное это то, что у объекта (в моём случае gridView) нет готовых событий для данного свойства на которые можно подписаться. Поэтому и интересует как реализовать проверку значения любого свойства